# What do I need to run Sentry inside my django site

Tags: django

The sentry source code has a `wsgi.py` which uses some defaults in `server.py`. My goal is to run sentry as part of my django site. But I am not linking to the `wsgi.py` in apache2's `sites-enabled`. Should I copy the contents of `server.py` into my own `settings.py` to get it to work ? Currently by not doing anything, the values of the `SECRET_KEY` and `SENTRY_KEY` are different. Thus the client is unable to post exceptions to the sentry server.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to make sure of is that you have added sentry and raven to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py (after doing `pip install sentry`).

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'sentry',
    'raven.contrib.django',
)
```

Also, make sure you add sentry to your urls.py with:

```
url(r'^sentry/',include('sentry.web.urls')),
```